# Submitted applications for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: software-center, application-development, application-submission

Are the submitted desktop applications for Ubuntu reviewed and added to the Ubuntu software center anymore? Its been a month that I submitted an application named PLY Visualizer on developer.ubuntu.com and on the developers page it still says 'pending review'. I had previously submitted some applications and they were reviewed within a week.

Comment: They have thousands of apps to review, it takes time. I would suggest sending them a mail.